# Find all possible paths from top-left to bottom-right corner of 4x4 array

Tags: ruby

I've got some challenge to solve..

> A robot is located at the top-left corner of a 4x4 grid. The robot can move either up, down, left, or right, but can not visit the same spot twice. The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid.
>
> Print out the unique number of ways the robot can reach its destination.

I'm trying to solve it simply by checking all possible paths in a grid and counting all leading to exit position. Something like building a tree with all possible movements.

```
                              (0,0)

            (0,1)                               (1,0)

    (1,1)           (0,2)               (1,1)           (2,0)

(0,1)(1,2)(2,1)   (2,1)(3,0)             ***             ***

      ***            ***
```

I wrote some code....

```
class Robot

  def self.count_possible_ways

    board = Array.new(4,0) { Array.new(4,0) }

    @@count = 0

    find_possible_ways(board)
    print_output(board)
    puts "Ile razy: #{@@count}"
  end

  def self.find_possible_ways(board)

    entry_position_yx = [0,0]
    exit_position_yx = [3,3]

    actual_position = entry_position_yx

    board[actual_position[0]][actual_position[1]] = 1
    find_possible_ways_2(board,actual_position)
  end

  def self.find_possible_ways_2(board,actual_position)
    puts "Actual position: (#{actual_position[0]},#{actual_position[1]})"
    check_possible_moves(board,actual_position)
  end



  def self.check_possible_moves(board,actual_position)

    if actual_position[1] != 0
      if board[actual_position[0]][actual_position[1]-1] == 0
        board[actual_position[0]][actual_position[1]-1] = 1
        actual_position = [actual_position[0],actual_position[1]-1]
        if actual_position == [3,3]
          @@count +=1
        else
          find_possible_ways_2(board,actual_position)
        end
      end
    end
    if actual_position[1] != 3
      if board[actual_position[0]][actual_position[1]+1] == 0
        board[actual_position[0]][actual_position[1]+1] = 1
        actual_position = [actual_position[0],actual_position[1]+1]
        if actual_position == [3,3]
          @@count +=1
          else
          find_possible_ways_2(board,actual_position)
        end
      end
    end
    if actual_position[0] != 0
      if board[actual_position[0]-1][actual_position[1]] == 0
        board[actual_position[0]-1][actual_position[1]] = 1
        actual_position = [actual_position[0]-1,actual_position[1]]
        if actual_position == [3,3]
          @@count +=1
          else
          find_possible_ways_2(board,actual_position)
        end
      end
    end
    if actual_position[0] != 3
      if board[actual_position[0]+1][actual_position[1]] == 0

        board[actual_position[0]+1][actual_position[1]] = 1
        actual_position = [actual_position[0]+1,actual_position[1]]
        if actual_position == [3,3]
          @@count +=1
          else
          find_possible_ways_2(board,actual_position)
        end
      end
    end
  end



  def self.print_output(board)
    board.each do |row|
      puts row.join(" ")
    end
  end
end


Robot.count_possible_ways
```

..but my problem is.... that in every step (like every new branch of path) i would like to create a new independent array. I cant check every possible path on the same array. I think a must do it using a Recursion but i don't know how to code it.

I'm not sure if I explained it well but i need something like creating a new object (array) every time my path is splitting into two new paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, recursion is the way to go.

**Code**

```
def paths(grid, partial_path = [[0,0]], paths = [])
  return paths if grid.empty?
  last_cell = partial_path.last
  grid.each do |cell|
    if adjacent?(last_cell,cell)
      pp = partial_path + [cell]
      if cell == [3,3]
        paths << pp
      else
        paths(grid-[cell], pp, paths)
      end
    end  
  end
  paths
end

def adjacent?(a,b)
  ra, ca = a
  rb, cb = b
  ((ra==rb) && (ca==cb+1 || ca==cb-1)) ||
  ((ca==cb) && (ra==rb+1 || ra==rb-1))
end
```

**Calculation**

```
grid = Array.new(16) { |i| i.divmod(4) } - [[0, 0]]
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0],
  #    [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]

paths(grid).size
  #=> 184

paths(grid).values_at(34, 72, 138)
  #=> [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 0], [2, 0],
  #     [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]],
  #
  #    [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [2, 2],
  #     [2, 1], [2, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]],
  #
  #    [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 2],
  #     [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]]
```

If the robot were allowed to also move on diagonals, change `adjacent` to:

```
def adjacent?(a,b)
  ((a.first-b.first).abs <= 1) && ((a.last-b.last).abs <= 1)
end
```

With that change, `paths(grid).size #=> 96371`.

@Halfbit wrote some code to display the robot's wanderings. (See his comment for the link). Here are 79 of the 184 paths.

[image]

---

```
               (105 paths not shown)
```

---

[image]

Comment: if you want to see it walk/how the algo does ... http://keepitsimple-soft.com/public/robot_goes

Comment: @halfbit, very cool! Thanks! It seems there is a method to the robot's madness.

Comment: How did you figure it @Cary Swoveland? :)

Comment: I just pretended to be the robot. If I knew the path that got me to my present location, how would I determine my next possible moves? I'd just look at all squares I hadn't been to and see which were adjacent. (If I'd boxed myself in, there wouldn't be any.) I'd then check each adjacent cell. If it was `[3,3]`, I'd have found a new path from top-left to bottom-right, so I'd add that to `path`; if not I'd pass the path, updated with a new last cell (plus `grid` without that cell), to the next lower level.

Comment: @halfbit, I'd like your permission to display part or all of your graphic with my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: given! Including code now. If you want I put the smal changes for variale input (3,3, start and end point) i had to make to yours on the page,  too.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Sleeping a night over it; realized, that I have overseen the 'all pathes' in your question, so my Answer is wrong, because you get only all shortest pathes.
I do not delete the "answer" because it may be useful for some one else

---

Although this sounds like 'homework' or because it sounds like that, I answer with a completely different algorithm:

you need only one array ...

Since the robot is not allowed to 'go back' i.e. use a point twice, you can use the logic, that is used for printed circut board design: just number the possible (empty) neighbour squares ...
(- stands for empty)

1st

```
1 - - -
- - - -
- - - -
- - - -
```

2nd

```
1 2 - -
2 - - - 
- - - - 
- - - -
```

last

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
```

now go back from 7 (the highest) to the lower ones ...
7-6-5-4-3-2-1 ...

isnt that a clever algo? (code it by your self ;-)

it works even for that (S: start, E: end & X blocked)... (probaly your next homework)

```
S - - - X -
- - X - - -
- - X - - -
X X X X - X
E - - - - -
```

->

```
S 2 3 4 X 8
2 3 X 5 6 7
3 4 X 6 7 8
X X X X 8 X
E C B A 9 A
```

Comment: Algorithm is smart but i think it is finding only shortest way to exit and I need to find number of all possible, unique paths.